# best way to store todo lists, reminders and their linked data on disk

Tags: database, file, tree, storage

I am doing a side-project on a productivity tool that has the following features:
 to-do lists, appointments (as to-do), goals (that are broken down into action steps -> to-do), recurring to-do's everyday, etc. What is the best way to store this information?

1. I use a database, then everytime the program will have to query the database. Being a 'small' program, this would be inefficient.
2. I use files on disk, then they would have to be read, and the information would have to be sorted everytime.
3. Can I see efficiency using files, and multiple hash / search trees that contain the information? That would make searching much easier? What about manipulation?

The context of the problem is 80% searching / retrieval :: 20% manipulation / creation
What form of data storage would be simple, efficient?
The data contains items such as Strings, DateTime, Attributes(Priority, belonging to certain group etc).

Answer (score 0):

I think SQLite is a good choice for this. Since you aren't storing that much data you can search however you want using SQL `LIKE` and not really worry about speed hits.